# Title of reprintfrom in biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex-chicago

I'm having trouble getting the original collection of a reprinted work to show in a bibliographic entry. I'm using biblatex-chicago, biber, Xelatex.

Here's my code:

```
@inbook{junghans, 
    title={Johann Sebastian Bach als Schüler der Partikularschule zu St. Michaelis in Lüneburg, oder Lüneburg eine Pflegstätte kirchlicher Musik}, 
    author={Wilhelm C. Junghans}, 
    pages={31-74},
    crossref = {bachBook},
    relatedtype={reprintfrom},
    related={junghansOrig}
}

@book{junghansOrig,
    title={Programm des Johanneums zu Lüneburg, Ostern 1870},
    pages={3-42},
    location={Lüneburg},
    publisher={Stern'schen Buchdruckerei},
    date={1970}
}

@book{bachBook,
    location={Burlington, Vermont},  
    title={Bach},
    publisher={Ashgate}, 
    editor = {Yo Tomita},
    year={2011},
    keywords={Secondary}
}
```

I get:

> Junghans, Wilhelm C. “Johann Sebastian Bach als Schüler der
> Partikularschule zu St. Michaelis in Lüneburg, oder Lüneburg eine
> Pflegstätte kirchlicher Musik.” In *Bach*, edited by Yo Tomita, 31–
> 74. Burlington, Vermont: Ashgate, 2011. Reprinted from (Lüneburg: Stern’schen Buchdruckerei, 1970), 3–42.

I want:

> Junghans, Wilhelm C. “Johann Sebastian Bach als Schüler der
> Partikularschule zu St. Michaelis in Lüneburg, oder Lüneburg eine
> Pflegstätte kirchlicher Musik.” In *Bach*, edited by Yo Tomita, 31–
> 74. Burlington, Vermont: Ashgate, 2011. Reprinted from *Programm des Johanneums zu Lüneburg, Ostern 1870* (Lüneburg: Stern’schen
> Buchdruckerei, 1970), 3–42.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `maintitle` instead of `title` in the `junghansOrig` entry achieved the desired result.